# Show a button when clicking an ImageView inside a ListView

Tags: android

My problem is that I need to show a button in when I click an `ImageView` in a `ListView`.
The button id is eliminarMen in `main.xml`.

I tried with inflate, inside the ArrayAdapter class, but the button isn`t showing.

This is the code of ArrayAdapter class:

```
package sms.manager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Array extends ArrayAdapter{

private String[] datos;
private ImageView img;
private Button eliminar;


public Array(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] items) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

   this.datos=items;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View v=convertView;

    if(v==null){
      LayoutInflater 
    vi=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
      v=vi.inflate(R.layout.cheks, null); 

    }

        LayoutInflater 
    vi=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View view=null;
        view=vi.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        eliminar=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.eliminarMen);


        TextView contiene=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contieneTexto);
        contiene.setText(datos[position]);

        img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        final ImageView [] imagen=new ImageView[datos.length];
        imagen[position]=img;
        imagen[position].setTag("unchecked");



        imagen[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (imagen[position].getTag()=="unchecked"){
              imagen[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
              imagen[position].setTag("checked");
            }
            else
            {

                             imagen[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.uncheck); 
                imagen[position].setTag("unchecked");
            }
        }

        });

    return v;
}
 }
```

Comment: Can you please show your `Activity` code and your `main.xml`?

Comment: I not know how to paste the code because the only thing that lets me add are comments.
How should I do?

Comment: sorry, there I could paste the code

Answer (score 0):

To get something to happen in your activity from an OnClick in your adapter you would have to use an interface like below:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public interface OnImageClickListener {
        public void onImageClick(int id);
    }

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ....

        imagen[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OnImageClickListener activity = (OnImageClickListener) getContext();
                activity.onImageClick(R.id.some_image_id);
            }
        });

        .....

        return v;
    }
}
```

Then your Activity needs to implement this Interface:

```
   public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity implements OnImageClickListener{

        ImageView someImageView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

            someImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onImageClick(int id) {
            someImageView.setImageResource(id);
        }
    }
```

If your Activity didn't implement this interface you would get an error in your LogCat

*EDIT*

Just noticed you want to show a button and not show an image. It's pretty similar you would still use an interface, it would mean you don't need to pass the id reference and in your Activity `onImageClick()` just use `setVisibility` (assuming the button was set to `android:visibility="gone"` in your XML layout.

Comment: I used setVisibility in the posted code, inside the onClick event, but the button isn`t showing.In the LogCat isn`t errors, but the button isn`t showing.How resolver this?.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm Spanish this is the traduction:

I am using the code posted setvisivility within the onClick event, but the button is not being displayed. in logcat no errors, but the button is not being displayed. How to solve this?
is as good as well but never displayed.The visibility of button is GONE by default in the main.xml.
seems to inflate does not work, but the code is fine.

Comment: Change the visibility in the XML to visible, can you see it then? Put a log msg in onImageClick() `Log.i("TAG", "Is in onImageClick");`to see if it is reaching that far. Debug debug debug

Comment: I changed the visivility in the main and is displayed.I cut the line of visibility of the button and paste this out of image Click event and continues the same way(the button is not being displayed).

Comment: if i have for example: a button in other xml and i Inflate this from the main.xml, the situation is the same, the button not show.I verified that the setVisibility Button propertie is visible when this is inflated and setVisibility propertie is VISIBLE!!!seems as if inflated but never shown.i tried with Log.i and the text in LogCat is displayed more than five times when clickin in the image.that amount of times to repeat that I think is equal to the amount of data that happened to arrayadapter from the main

Comment: Sorry your english isn't good enough for me to understand. The above code words. You need to have the button your trying to show already in the XML layout declaration and all you do is change its visibility and it will work. The onClick is called five times because your onClick is in a loop.

Comment: to simplify the situation, how do I make visible the button of the main.xml from another class, in my case from the ArrayAdapter class,assuming the button was set to android:visibility="gone"

Comment: I showed you. Use the interface and `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Answer (score 0):

this is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:onClick="eliminar">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/nuevo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

and this is the activity code:

```
package sms.manager;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSManagerActivity extends Activity implements        

OnItemClickListener,OnTouchListener  {

private String numero,texto,recibeNumBandera="";
public Button nuevo_mensaje,marcarVarios,eliminarMen;
public ListView mensajes;
private String []almacenaNombres,almacenaNumeros,datos,datos2;
private int posicion,n,cantFilas=0,cant,posicionInfo=0;
private ArrayAdapter<?> adaptador;
public boolean entra=true,banderaServicio=true,inhabilitar=true;
private TimerTask task;
private Handler handler=new Handler();
private Timer t=new Timer();
private String maximo="";
private TableRow menu,nuevo,tableRow1;
private TextView contienetexto;
public ImageView icono;
private LinearLayout layoutCheks,linearMain;
private Array array;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    mensajes=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mensajes);
    mensajes.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    menu=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    marcarVarios=(Button)findViewById(R.id.marcarVarios);
    eliminarMen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.eliminarMen);
    nuevo=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.nuevo);
    registerForContextMenu(mensajes);
    nuevo_mensaje=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nuevo_mensaje);
    nuevo_mensaje.setOnTouchListener(this);
    LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService   

  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = infl.inflate(R.layout.cheks,null);
    icono=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icono.setVisibility(8);

    Intent service = new Intent(this, Servicios.class);
    startService(service);


  llenarList();

  task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            marcar();

                        }

               });
        }};


        t.schedule(task, 500, 500);  





}

public boolean  onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    final Principal_mensajes cierraPrin= new Principal_mensajes();
    final ListaContactos lista= new ListaContactos();
    final Conversaciones conv= new Conversaciones();

    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("SMS Manager se cerrará")  
        .setCancelable(false)       
        .setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                

            cierraPrin.finish();
            lista.finish();
            conv.finish();
            finish();

        }     
        })       
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                
           dialog.cancel();        
            }

        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
        cierraPrin.finish();
        lista.finish();
        conv.finish();
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    else  if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){

        menu.setVisibility(0);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}





@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

if (inhabilitar){
 BaseDeDatos db2=new BaseDeDatos  
      (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
      SQLiteDatabase desmarca=db2.getWritableDatabase(); 
      desmarca.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones SET noLeido='' WHERE number='" +   
      almacenaNumeros[position] + "'");
      desmarca.close();
      db2.close();

      llenarList();

      Intent abreConversacion=new Intent(this,Conversaciones.class);
 abreConversacion.putExtra("contactoNom", almacenaNombres[position]);
 abreConversacion.putExtra("contactoNum", almacenaNumeros[position]);
 startActivity(abreConversacion);
}



} 



public void llenarList(){


  BaseDeDatos suplente=new BaseDeDatos(this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
       SQLiteDatabase base=suplente.getReadableDatabase(); 
       Cursor cursor=base.rawQuery("SELECT *,count(body) FROM conversaciones GROUP BY 
       number ORDER BY address ASC",null);

  cantFilas=cursor.getCount();

  String fecha="";
  String nombre="";
  String cuerpo="";
  String numero="";
  String cantidad="";
  String noLeido="";



  datos=new String[cursor.getCount()];
  almacenaNombres=new String[cursor.getCount()];
  almacenaNumeros=new String[cursor.getCount()];



  n=-1;

  while (cursor.moveToNext()){

    fecha=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("date")));
    nombre=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("address")));
    cuerpo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("body")));
    noLeido=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("noLeido")));
    numero=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("number")));
    cantidad=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("count(body)")));


    if (cuerpo.length()>25){
     cuerpo=cuerpo.substring(0,25) + "...";
    }

    if (!(noLeido!=null)){
        noLeido="";
    }

    n++;

    if (nombre.equals("No agendado")){
        datos[n]=noLeido + numero + "\n" + fecha + "\n" + cuerpo + "\n(" + 
               cantidad + ") mensajes";
    }
    else
       {
        datos[n]=noLeido + nombre + "\n" + fecha + "\n" + cuerpo + "\n(" + cantidad 
         + ") mensajes";
       }

    almacenaNombres[n]=nombre;
    almacenaNumeros[n]=numero;

  }

  cursor.close();
  base.close();
  suplente.close();


  if (cantFilas!=0){
     adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<Object>
     (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
     mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador); 
  }
 else
 {
    Toast ninguno=Toast.makeText(SMSManagerActivity.this,"Lista de mensajes 
      vacía",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    ninguno.show();

 }
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
if (arg0.getId()==nuevo_mensaje.getId()){
    Intent nuevo = new Intent(this,Principal_mensajes.class);
    startActivity(nuevo);
    return true;

}
return false;
}



public void marcar(){

SharedPreferences p=getSharedPreferences("DatosNumero",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
     recibeNumBandera=p.getString("numeroPasado",""); 

if (!recibeNumBandera.equals("")){
     task.cancel(); 

    BaseDeDatos db=new BaseDeDatos(SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", 
   null,5); 
    SQLiteDatabase insertar=db.getWritableDatabase(); 

    insertar.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones SET noLeido='' WHERE number='" +  
     recibeNumBandera + "'");
    insertar.close();
    db.close();


    BaseDeDatos sel=new BaseDeDatos
    (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
    SQLiteDatabase max=sel.getReadableDatabase(); 

    Cursor cursorMax=max.rawQuery("SELECT max(id) as maximo FROM conversaciones WHERE 
    number='" + recibeNumBandera + "'",null);


    while (cursorMax.moveToNext()){
    maximo = cursorMax.getString(cursorMax.getColumnIndex(("maximo")));
    }
    cursorMax.close();
    max.close();
    sel.close();

     BaseDeDatos db3=new BaseDeDatos
     (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
    SQLiteDatabase insertar2=db3.getWritableDatabase(); 
    insertar2.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones SET noLeido='*' WHERE number='" + 
     recibeNumBandera + "'  AND  id='" + maximo + "'");
    insertar2.close();
    db3.close();

    BaseDeDatos PasaNum2=new BaseDeDatos
   (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
    SQLiteDatabase paraEsc=PasaNum2.getWritableDatabase(); 
    paraEsc.execSQL("DELETE FROM PasaNum");
    paraEsc.close();
    PasaNum2.close();

    llenarList();

    SharedPreferences pr=getSharedPreferences
    ("DatosNumero",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor ed=pr.edit(); 
    ed.putString("numeroPasado","" ); 
    ed.commit(); 

    task.run();  

 }
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)
 menuInfo;
 menu.setHeaderTitle(almacenaNombres[info.position]);

 posicionInfo=info.position; 

 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ver");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Eliminar conversación");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

if(item.getTitle()=="Ver"){

 Intent abreConversacion2=new Intent(this,Conversaciones.class);
 abreConversacion2.putExtra("contactoNom", almacenaNombres[posicionInfo]);
 abreConversacion2.putExtra("contactoNum", almacenaNumeros[posicionInfo]);
 startActivity(abreConversacion2);
    return true;
}
else if(item.getTitle()=="Eliminar conversación"){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Confirmación");
    builder.setMessage("Está seguro de eliminar la conversación con " + 
         almacenaNombres[posicionInfo] + "?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     BaseDeDatos administraM=new BaseDeDatos
     (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
     SQLiteDatabase elimina=administraM.getWritableDatabase(); 
     elimina.execSQL("DELETE FROM conversaciones WHERE address='" + almacenaNombres
     [posicionInfo] + "'");
     elimina.close();
     administraM.close();

     BaseDeDatos administraM2=new BaseDeDatos
     (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
     SQLiteDatabase elimina2=administraM2.getWritableDatabase(); 
     elimina2.execSQL("DELETE FROM recibidos WHERE address='" + almacenaNombres
     [posicionInfo] + "'");
     elimina2.close();
     administraM2.close();

     BaseDeDatos administraM3=new BaseDeDatos
      (SMSManagerActivity.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,5); 
     SQLiteDatabase elimina3=administraM3.getWritableDatabase(); 
     elimina3.execSQL("DELETE FROM enviados WHERE address='" + almacenaNombres
     [posicionInfo] + "'");
     elimina3.close();
     administraM3.close();

     llenarList();

    }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                
       dialog.cancel();        
        }

    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

   return true; 
}
else
{
    return false;
}

}

public void marcar(View view){

nuevo.setVisibility(8);
menu.setVisibility(8);
inhabilitar=false;


array= new Array(this,R.layout.main,datos);
mensajes.setAdapter(array);

}

public void eliminar(View view){

}



}
```